# Approximating function $f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{e^{x}}}$

Tags: functions, approximation, pade-approximation

I've been tryng to find a good (accurate) low order (2-3) approximation for functions $e^x$ and $2^x$. 
Found out that taking square root of the function improves accuracy a bit ... and taking multiple square roots even more. So, approximating improves accuracy as seen in example plots:

1. [$f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{e^{x}}}$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dvbpscgctf)
2. [$f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{e^{x}}}}$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wfxtkwgkhb)

I've noticed that in case of approximation of $2^x$, $f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2^{x}}}}$ (i.e. $2^\frac x{2^3}$ ) produces almost straight line to approximate (sollya code for 3rd order approximation)

```
f=sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(2^x))))
p=remez(f,3,dom_log);
accurateinfnorm((((p^2)^2)^2)^2-2^x,[-0.5;0.5],20); 2.538871513024787418544292449951171875e-8
dirtyinfnorm((((p^2)^2)^2)^2-2^x,[-0.5;0.5]); 2.53887148348479669618870887598400206143150554903096e-8
```

[image]

Errors compared to $2^x$ :

[image]
[image]
*remez(2^x,3,[-0.5;0.5]);*

...

[image]
*remez(sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(2^x))),3,[-0.5;0.5]);*

... which sure could help to find a good approximation but,... are there drawbacks in doing it this way?

Edit: My intention is to use this approximation in an implementation the way as like done [here](https://root.cern.ch/doc/v606/exp_8h_source.html).

Comment: Do you mean you are approximating $e^x$ and $2^x$ by polynomials of degree $2$ or $3$? And what improves the accuracy; taking the square roots of $e^x$ and $2^x$ and approximating those, or simply also taking the square roots of the approximations?

Comment: And of course taking succesive square roots yields something 'closer to a line' because
$$\sqrt{2^x}=(2^x)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}=2^{\tfrac{x}{2}},$$
so taking square roots is the same as scaling the $x$-axis by a factor of $2$, i.e. a horizontal stretching of a factor $2$.

Comment: This really makes no sense at all. You are trying to estimate a function by using a function that has the function inside of it? You do realize that the point of estimation is to use a simpler function to estimate said function.

Comment: This is not going to help you to get better approximation of the original function because to get that approximation you would need to square your initial approximation.

Comment: This will, in fact, give a worse approximation as you increase the square roots (with the limit of the sequence of these approximations being the constant $x\mapsto 1$ map)

Comment: If you'd like an approximation to the exponential function, see https://math.stackexchange.com/1239352/. Techniques typically involve vector rotation, interpolation, Taylor series and Pade approximants. Unfortunately, you're unlikely to find anything better without some high level mathematical trickery.

Comment: Added some plots to show the differences.

Comment: As pointed out by @Servaes, it's just another way to represent $2^\frac x{2^{2n}}$ ... but, are there any drawbacks using $\sqrt{}$ 's ?

Answer (score 1):

Since, for any positive number, you can write
$$a^x=e^{x\log(a)}$$ and that
$$\sqrt{a^x}=e^{\frac 12 x\log(a)}\qquad \sqrt{\sqrt{a^x}}=e^{\frac 14 x\log(a)}\qquad\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{a^x}}}=e^{\frac 18 x\log(a)}$$ and so on
we can build the $[n,n]$ Padé approximants
$$e^{kx}=\frac{1+\frac{k }{2}x+\frac{k^2 }{12}x^2 } {1-\frac{k }{2}x+\frac{k^2 }{12}x^2  }\tag 1$$
$$e^{kx}=\frac{1+\frac{k}{2}x+\frac{k^2 }{10}x^2+\frac{k^3 }{120}x^3 } {1-\frac{k}{2}x+\frac{k^2 }{10}x^2-\frac{k^3 }{120}x^3  }\tag 2$$

For the case of
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2^x}}}$$ using $(2)$ for the range $-\frac 12 \leq x \leq \frac 12$, the maximum absolute error is (at the bound) $3.06 \times 10^{-12}$